# Is there way to see kahaDB logs in AWS using amazonMQ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, activemq-classic, amazon-mq, kahadb

We are in the process of migrating from activeMQ to **amazonMQ** on AWS. ActiveMQ and AmazonMQ internally uses kahaDB as there data store. 
Earlier we were able to see kahaDB logs files while using activeMQ on data center is there a similar way of seeing the **kahadb logs file on AWS** while using amazonMQ?

1. Tried enabling cloudwatch logs but it contains general and audit logs of amazonMQ.

Comment: Anyone has any pointers on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked with AWS technical team, they don't allow to access the kahaDB logs.